# Как строку scroll page опустить как шторку?(см. гиф)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день. Как сделать также как в примере? то есть опускающуюся шторку с менюшками которые в scrolle?(пример из приложения - Радио)

[image: пример]

Answer (score 1):

Как варимант, можно поискать подобную готовую реализацию:

- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls
- http://code4app.net/

Или можно попробовать самостоятельно разработать, например, путем содания выпадающего меню в отдельном UIViewController. А анимацию реализовать используя UIViewController custom transitions, при этом создать custom animator - класс реализующий итерфейсы ( *UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning*, *UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning* и *UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate*) для контроля анимации перехода между UIViewConrtoller таким образом И передать этому классу всю логику анимации. Более-менее, простой пример для ознакомления: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/